# Insert into table class

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

This class should function as a simple insert into table. What do you think about it? How can I make my code better?

```
class addProfile{
private $profileName;
private $profileEmail;
private $profileFromName;
private $profileReplaytToEmail;

public function __construct($profileName,$profileEmail,$profileFromName,$profileReplayToEmail){
    $this->profileEmail = $profileEmail;
    $this->profileFromName = $profileFromName;
    $this->profileName = $profileName;
    $this->profileReplaytToEmail = $profileReplayToEmail;
}

public function postProfile($profileName,$profileEmail,$profileFromName,$profileReplayToEmail){
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO SendingProfiles (fromemail,Fromname,Profilename,replaytoemail)
    VALUES ('$profileName','$profileEmail','$profileFromName','$profileReplayToEmail')");
    $stmt->bind_param($profileName,$profileEmail,$profileFromName,$profileReplayToEmail);

    if ($stmt->execute()){
        echo "the record added";
    }else{
        echo "Failed";
    }

    $stmt->close();


}

public function __destruct(){
    $this->mysqli->close();
}

}

$profileName = $_POST['profilename'];
$profileEmail = $_POST['fromemail'];
$profileFromName = $_POST['fromname'];
$profileReplayToEmail = $_POST['replaytoemail'];

$var = new addProfile();
$var->postProfile($profileName, $profileEmail, $profileFromName, $profileReplayToEmail)
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your use of MySQLi. You insert the values into the SQL command string first, and after that you bind them to the statement. It might work, but the binding serves no purpose and the values are inserted without escaping them, or checking their validity. Apart from that, there is the problem that this code is so minimal that there's not much to review.

Answer (score 3):

There's very little to review.

**Variable Names**

Use full names for variables, avoid short forms of those words/abbreviations. For example, you wrote, `$stmt`, instead you could write `$statement` to increase the readability of the code.

**Class Names**

Your class name, `addProfile` is not really suitable to give the image of the class. Why not name it, `CreateUserProfile` since that is what it does?

Also, class names should be declared StudlyCaps.

**Validation Checks**

Why not perform validation checks for what user has input? For example check if the variables are empty or not.

**Coding Standards**

Your coding style does not meet the [coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

**Working Code**

You have not provided us with a working code, as there would be an error with bind_param() because you haven't used any '?' and directly injected the variables like this, which is vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO SendingProfiles (fromemail,Fromname,Profilename,replaytoemail)
    VALUES ('$profileName','$profileEmail','$profileFromName','$profileReplayToEmail')");
```

Instead, do this:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO SendingProfiles(fromemail, Fromname, Profilename, replaytoemail) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: I did include that.

Answer (score 3):

Also to add onto @HassanAlthaf's answer above you need to bind parameters like below:

```
 $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$profileName,$profileEmail,$profileFromName,$profileReplayToEmail);
```

The `s` is for strings and matches each parameter variable.
`i` is for integer, `d` for double, `b` for blob. Refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more info.